# Finding count of NA values for combination of columns in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataset as follows,

```
(dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="a    b
1    2
NA   1
1    NA
NA   NA
1    2
NA   3"))

#    a  b
# 1  1  2
# 2 NA  1
# 3  1 NA
# 4 NA NA
# 5  1  2
# 6 NA  3
```

I am thinking how we can get the count of NA values for combination of two columns. My output should be like,

```
No NA - 2
1st column NA - 2
2nd column NA - 1
Both NA - 1
```

I am not getting an idea how to do this for a combination of columns. Can anybody help me?

Comment: @rawr this one does not give the actual output. I want the count. and also when there are more values, number of rows are too much.

Comment: Yeah still trying it.

Comment: @rawr, I am doing review service and fail to see how this question has only minor issues (i disagree with the audit). It fails to show effort on the side of the questioner. Please enlighten me.

Comment: @benjamin I'm not sure what you're asking me. my edits made the example data reproducible so that one can copy and use the code in the answer below. I agree that no effort was shown

Comment: @rawr, Your edits are fine. I failed a test in the triage section of SO in an audit that regarded this question as salvageable, where I did not. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`table` it up:

```
table(lapply(dd, is.na))

#       b
#a       FALSE TRUE
#  FALSE     2    1
#  TRUE      2    1
```

And if you need a vector for subsetting purposes, since `interaction` gives:

```
interaction(lapply(dd,is.na))
#[1] FALSE.FALSE TRUE.FALSE  FALSE.TRUE  TRUE.TRUE   FALSE.FALSE TRUE.FALSE 
#Levels: FALSE.FALSE TRUE.FALSE FALSE.TRUE TRUE.TRUE
```

You can do:

```
vec <- c("none","first","second","both")[interaction(lapply(dd,is.na))]
#[1] none   first  second both   none   first

table(vec)
#vec
#  none  first second   both 
#     2      2      1      1
```

Comment: The latter approach will produce the most digestible results when you've got more than 2 columns.

Comment: @thelatemail  Thanks a lot.. You made it look very easy!!